# How to create hyperlinks in jquery

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

Below is a code which creates the black text on the attached image..

It's a drawing done in jquery. I need to make these circles hyperlinks(in the image). Whenever those circles will be clicked, it will open another tab. any ideas how to do it?

```
function oncanvasmousemove(evt) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    lastTimeMouseMoved = new Date().getTime();
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
        if (currentTime - lastTimeMouseMoved > 300) {
            var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
            var tC, isMatched = false;
            for (c = 0; c < circles.length; c++) {
                tC = circles[c];
                if (mousePos.DistanceTo(tC.centerX, tC.centerY) < tC.Radius + 5) {
                    isMatched = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isMatched === true) {
                $("#tooltip").html(tC.Text).css({
                    'top': mousePos.Y + canvasoffset.top - 40,
                        'left': mousePos.X + canvasoffset.left - $("#tooltip").width() / 2
                }).show();
            } else {
                $("#tooltip").click(function () {
                    alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
                });
            }
        }
    }, 300);
}
```

Comment: There is no attached image.

Comment: sorry i am unable to attach image because of reputation points..  image is a flowchart of many processes represented as circles and linked with arrows. i want these circles to be hyperlink.

Comment: You can try to store the hyperlinks in your circles array. Then in your matching loop you can get the hyperlink for the clicked circle and open the link in new window via `window.open('url', 'window name', '_blank');`

Comment: hey viktor, thanks for this solution, but i am having trouble in passing the hyperlinks to function and please tell me what will be window name?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**We can make use of map and area tags to link many hyperlinks to image for particular co-ordinates.**

By using these tags we can attach more hyperlinks to a single image based on the co-ordinates.

Here is the sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click on the sun or on one of the planets to watch it closer:</p>

<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" alt="Sun" href="sun.htm">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" alt="Mercury" href="mercur.htm">
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" alt="Venus" href="venus.htm">
</map>

</body>
</html>
```

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap)

Hope this will help  you.

Comment: thanks for this answer.. but i hav not used image.. its a drawing i made using jquery which is similar to flow charts.. how to use this usemap attribute there?